# Can I use spring data jpa with Micronaut?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, micronaut

I would like to extend my TestRepository interface with JpaRepository and utilize the features such as jpa method queries, paging and sorting without manually defining entity manager bean and without writing any sql. 
P.S. In micronaut project

Comment: Here in documentation I see reference to Spring Data https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#introductionAdvice but not any example

Comment: What specifically do you want to do?

Comment: Use JpaRespository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit -  July 2019

They have announced a spring data equivalent named [Micronaut Data](https://objectcomputing.com/news/2019/07/18/unleashing-predator-precomputed-data-repositories)

---

Micronaut [does not support Spring's AOP implementation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html#springLimitations) right now. So you should not expect to use an object as Repository by simply implementing `JpaRepository<T,ID>`

However you can write a spring based app/library then add this jar as a micronaut project dependency... It should work in theory. Maybe some kind of bridge needed to share environment/profile info and retrieve this repositories to micronaut context

Or, as mentinoned in comments, you can write your own Repository stubs with [Introduction Advice](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#introductionAdvice) of micronaut. If you generally use `@Query` annotation in spring repositories, it should be quite easy to implement an equivalent for micronaut app

Answer (score 2):

The Predator proyect was renamed Micronaut Data. There are already maven packages for [milestone 1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micronaut.data).

The [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html) is quite good. You can use the same JPA annotated model with MicronautData [repositories](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#repositories). You can use it with or without Hibernate. It is as easy as:

```
@Repository 
interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> { 
    Book find(String title);
}
```

On the other hand. It seems that Spring repositories can be used with micronaut. Look at this [official example](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/tree/master/examples/example-jdbc-spring)

Comment: Thanks will check it out !